# Generating a new filename to an uploaded file if it already exists (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, upload

Didn't find a Node.js answer.

I got this route where I'm saving a file.
(I'm using the `express-fileupload` package to do so)

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
  }

  const file = req.files.file;

  file.mv(`public/uploads/${file.name}`, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}` });
  });
});
```

How can I:

1. Check if the filename already exists?
2. Rename and save it with a different name?

UPDATE: I found how to check if the file exists:

```
if (fs.existsSync(`public/uploads/${file.name}`)) {
  console.error('file exists')
}
```

Will get along with renaming it, tnx

Comment: Why not simply check with `fs` if the filename already exist on the target dir and after the check rename or do something? Seems that the plugin doesn't offer this feature out of the box but is very trivial implement to implement by hand.

Comment: I updated the question with something I tried, is that what u meant?

Comment: Ok, got it done. Thanks